# Does an ajax request cause an asp.net session to be renew?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, session

Have been working on detecting a timeout on an asp.net project. Have an ajax function that checks every 5 seconds to see if the session has expired. Without the ajax function checking, it actually expires after a minute, but if I keep the function on, it keeps sending me an "active" status. So I wonder, does my ajax function/request is keeping the session alive ?

**Ajax function:**

```
             function isSessionAlive(){
                await jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'coolpage.aspx/hello',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.info("status: ", response);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    console.info("status: ", response);
                },
                cache:false
            });}
```

**Asp.net page method**

```
    //[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [WebMethod]
    public static string hello()
    {
        //return (HttpContext.Current.Session["dummy"] == null) ? "expired" : "active";

        if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                string cookieHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if ((null != cookieHeader) && (cookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                {
                    return "expired";
                }
            }
        }

        return "active";

        // return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ?  "active":"expired";

    }
```

Comment: YES! it seems to be the case with you!! The AJAX request to check the session timeout is actually keeping your session active. With each request to your backend, the sliding session expiration window gets reset. Instead of checking this with the server, you can save a session expiration time in the cookie and verify it.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much. Decided to create a hidden element and just update it on postbacks after checking the session null value of any variable. ... thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use setInterval function in ajax.

```
setInterval(function(){
   $.get('coolpage.aspx/hello');
}, 300000); // 5mins
```

Comment: Thanks .... and yeah, the fn is actually being called from an interval (not shown).

Answer (score 0):

If your session has expired, so destroy your session and return "expired". After calling ajax(document.ready), you have to check your session value using if and else.